# Ambiguous template specialization with concepts and real types: which compiler is right?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-specialization, c++-concepts, explicit-specialization

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include<concepts>

template<typename>
void foo() { }

template<std::integral> 
void foo() { }

template<> 
void foo<bool>() { }

int main() { foo<bool>(); }
```

It compiles without issues under recent Clang and MSVC, but not GCC ([godbolt link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMwAcpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQSXKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BeqnpjgJhEdEscQlJdpgOmUIETMQE2T5%2BgbaY9oUMdQ0ExVGx8Ym29Y3NuZWjfeEDZUNcAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDM4cjeWCZbbmgM68kECofYJhoAggSYLMkGD4duBACeyYysmFc3twAbqg8OgANT8VAQBZgkwAdgssLhABEAQCHk8Xn8jgoCOgQCBwg9gMQxFdYXdgaCIagoTD4Yj4ai7ujHs8mK8juSAVTwZC3jFabQrtCkYyUWi7kSwSwmOFRQyaagBUKRQtDuLkRwlrROABWXh%2BDhaUioThuazWMEKFZrTCwsxbHikAiabVLADW/gAnAA6DSSLgab16gLegNBkNBXUcSSGt2mzi8BQgDQut1LOCwGBQHMQJBoJ50eLkSiF5LFhJ7QzALhwjRJLCAvDrABqeEwAHcAPLfI3Omi0B7EFMQGIJmLhBofTjOyfMYgfbsxbTVV3cXiFtiCbsMWgz428LAxLzANxiWgpjekLCyoziQ83vDENd4QGYK8mzCqapeB6z3giQ6BNaDwGJSUXDwsAAl1iDwFgAKWKgDGABR2y7XtGBg/hBBEMR2CkGRBEUFR1EfXQkgMIwUEtSx9DAlNICWVBzkyK8AFpcXQQ5kVMSxrDME1UHfYg4KwRjoXaTpMhcBh3E8Fo9FCGZSnKPI0gyARxj8JJ8k0hh%2BlU%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%2BZvNtPzFjuh6yZCn7Fti4BkGQRKtl9Mw0oynaodygaCrhhGkcoIqSt9Rqgx1W9JIb0XA9RmD1HqO6bUOpdX5r1FMaZqZDTFgWeWlZJrTUVoCZAyRkgAH1ARcG9PgrEuJ8GqBiqrdWmB0JaywteQcetKAGxNKbA8c4pxmxXGuK2Utty2z3AeL2mATxngvFeZ07t7wbC9s%2BV8fsEyB2QH%2BGOgFBDAUfBHCCHxo4wTjvBW6yEmCoToWnbCsgs4ERzrIU6ZETS6C2EXai9drD0RiBXU0VcGBXgAPRcRLg3CwTdTQt1BG3Ji1kuiyXkjkbeA9ZjT3HiPLSW9h76T3o5JeXQV6L1njkuyKkh6TGcmkkpu8inr2Pj5O0/kT5BR6qFShsUWAKBwWCIhfoyEfXSttLK2xobvxpvDRGQxJIk3psVOBwUEFU1hqQL0f8AENkqiAsBECoExi2A056vVkHCzzMNEAo13qYPQRDWabB5q/SWtfW%2BXB7502CH03aSRM6HWsUReQed7E6ELldJgN1E71L5jMjgr0xp/k%2Bt9Baf0wR3Lvg/UG5z4jZTMG/ZBn9RnIyKmjX0BMwx4w0J1ImcJJARWgZMzqoLGmUyQRmA5qDjlvQmrLLB8RLkbGaTKNpt9Om%2Bm6QHF5oI9qWI%2BRIGxxEfnnRAE4gFQKeABXujs8mEL3rQrCktVp7T%2BXdORdLSG2wtgYvmSM7%2B4zWpUumbSvq9LBq4vRgS70RKSWSDJRSrZKqBZDMKrTSZMUUpwhKhFes3ow1cACHCIIZ89nzK9PWX0UZwyBmDKGZNd1tk0t2RTH1SqnkxpzZi0gIl0jOEkEAA%3D))

The build with GCC fails with:

```
error: ambiguous template specialization 'foo<bool>' for 'void foo()'
    9 | void foo<bool>() { }
      |      ^~~~~~~~~
note: candidates are: 'template<class> void foo()'
    3 | void foo() { }
      |      ^~~
note:                 'template<class>  requires  integral< <template-parameter-1-1> > void foo()'
    6 | void foo() { }
      |      ^~~
```

Which compiler is right? I'd say that GCC is wrong as there shouldn't be any ambiguity between a specialization through a concept (which keeps the code still generic) and an actual explicit specialization from the user which should always get priority.

Comment: Sure, specialization takes priority. The specialization was selected. The compiler is just having trouble figuring out ***which*** template is being specialized.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik `bool` seems to be more specific than `std::integral`. What rule is gcc referring in its diagnosis?!

Comment: fwiw godbolt has a conformance view which is quite handy for such comparisons https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3Kb8468ao

Comment: This is another reason to use function overloads instead of function template specializations.

Comment: "a specialization through a concept" but you don't have one.  The `std::integral`-constrained function template introduces an overload, not a specialization.  For a specialization you would need `template<std::integral TI> void foo<TI>() { }`, but that isn't allowed because it would be a partial specialization.

Comment: @Eugene: Unfortunately, overloads can't do everything that specializations can

Comment: This has nothing to do, whatsoever, with the fact that "bool seems to be more specific than integral". It is. Everyone agrees. Including the compiler, but the compiler simply does not understand whether `foo<bool>` specializes `foo<integral>` or `foo<typename>`. This is the ambiguity, as far as gcc is concerned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to decide which of the two `foo` function  templates your explicit specialization refers to, template argument deduction according to [[temp.deduct.decl]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.decl) is performed and partial ordering of function templates is applied to find a unique best match.

In your case template argument deduction against both candidates will succeed, but partial ordering of templates should succeed to determine the second template as the better match, as it is more constrained than the first one. (per [[temp.func.order]/6.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.func.order#6.4) and  [[temp.constr.order]/3.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.constr.order#3.2)).

So yes, I'd say GCC is wrong here. It doesn't seem to (fully) consider function template partial ordering.

Comment: For reference here's my current GCC bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111748